# How portable is OpenCV GPU code?

Tags: opencv, gpu

I have written a DLL in C++ which uses OpenCV. It is called by Labview. I found I can easily move it to other systems and use it with Labview by just including the necessary OpenCV DLLs in the folder of the actual DLL.

If I wrote a DLL that uses the OpenCV GPU capability on the first computer, could I transfer it as easily or would I need to recompile OpenCV for that particular system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Compute capability of different GPU is different. When you build the OpenCV with CUDA you build it for a range of compute_capability and a particular GPU architecture as long as the other machine has GPU of same architecture your code will work fine but if they differ from the build config that will trigger some OpenCV GPU errors